# Fetch specific string from string?

Tags: php

I have been trying to fetch a specific string from string for example from this string below

```
Scale Lengths

4 string model - E A D G
5 string model - B E A D G
6 string model - B E A D G C

B   37″
```

I want this part

```
4 string model - E A D G
5 string model - B E A D G
6 string model - B E A D G C
```

My code is this below and I am getting the correct answer

```
<?php
$str = 'Scale Lengths

4 string model - E A D G
5 string model - B E A D G
6 string model - B E A D G C

B
37″';

echo getBetween($str,'Scale Lengths','37″');
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
  $r = explode($start, $content);
  if (isset($r[1])){
      $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
      return $r[0];
  }
  return '';
}
 ?>
```

**Problem:** My problem is that my above code is only for static type of this string. For example if we change `37″` to something else like `28″` or `B` before this number to `C` it will start giving wrong answer.

Comment: you can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function instead of explode.

Comment: What about `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your code like this :

```
<?php
$str = 'Scale Lengths

4 string model - E A D G
5 string model - B E A D G
6 string model - B E A D G C

B
37″';

$get_occurence=explode(" ",$str);
$split=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', end($get_occurence));
$split=preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z]+/', '', $split);
$getBetween=getBetween($str,'Scale Lengths',$split);
$getLength=strlen($getBetween);
$getString=substr($getBetween,0,$getLength-3);

echo $getString;
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
$r = explode($start, $content);
if (isset($r[1])){
  $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
  return $r[0];
}
return '';
}


?>
```

I have edited some of my code, so you can dynamically replace B string with whatever you want to.

```
<?php
$str = 'Scale Lengths

4 string model - E A D G
5 string model - B E A D G
6 string model - B E A D G C

B
37″';

$get_occurence=explode(" ",$str);
$split=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', end($get_occurence));
$split=preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z]+/', '', $split);
$split_integer=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', end($get_occurence));
$split_integer=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z.]*/', '', $split_integer);
$getBetween=getBetween($str,'Scale Lengths',$split);
$getLength=strlen($getBetween);

$getString=substr($getBetween,0,$getLength-(strlen($split_integer)+1));

echo $getString;
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
$r = explode($start, $content);
if (isset($r[1])){
  $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
  return $r[0];
}
return '';
}


?>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: One question? What if we add some more string after `B 37″` like `B 37″ E 36.25″ ...` etc

Comment: if then, so you should edit $split and $split_integer variables to meet your requirements..

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

you can do someting like this :

```
$str = 'Scale Lengths

4 string model - E A D G
5 string model - B E A D G
6 string model - B E A D G C

B
37″';
// We split your string by lines.
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
// We filter this new array by sub array base on regex pattern.
$findedPattern = array_filter($lines, function($line) {
    // if is empty line, just ignore it.
    if(empty($line))
        return false;
    // We match all string who start by number, then followed b "string model - " and finally finish by letter and space.
    return preg_match('/^\d+ string model \- [A-Z\s]+\s+$/', $line);
});
```

[live sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ae3e42e413ee1226df68b6fd4ffaec94f194bc1)

### EDIT 1

if you don't have new line char.

you can do like this :

```
$str = 'Scale Lengths 4 string model - E A D G 5 string model - B E A D G 6 string model - B E A D G C B 37″';
preg_match_all('/\d+ string model \- [A-Z\s]+\s+/', $str, $m);
var_dump($m[0]);
```

[live sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7f87497724cdaee5c909120abaff26206a3ca36)

### EDIT 2

Because my previous pruposal still catch unwanted char. We need to add some additional control.

```
$str = 'Scale Lengths 4 string model - E A D G 5 string model - B E A D G 6 string model - B E A D G C B 37″';
preg_match_all('/(\d+) string model \- ([A-Z\s]+)\s+/', $str, $m);
$finded = [];
foreach($m as $index => $string) {
    $count = $m[1][$index];
    $oldMatched = $m[2][$index];
    // Base on the number capture before "string model", we valid if is what we expect.
    $t = preg_split("/[A-Z\s]{".($count * 2)."}/", $oldMatched);
    if(!empty($t[1])) {
        // if we find missmatch, we just fix it by removing unwanted chars.
        $newMatched = preg_replace("/".$t[1]."$/", '', $oldMatched);
        $finded[] = str_replace($oldMatched, $newMatched, $m[0][$index]);
    }
    else {
        $finded[] = $m[0][$index];
    }
}
```

[live sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b44a938e862c56a9a58d9b770fa02630d0194204)

Comment: alright, don't hesitate to adapt the regex if this one not detect string as expected.

Comment: Hmm, On live demo its right answer but on my localhost its giving `array(0) { }`

Comment: Can i see you real string ? is may uncover string pattern. For example this pattern is case sensitive.. Is can be one reason

Comment: Ok, you can consider this `$str = 'Scale Lengths 4 string model - E A D G 5 string model - B E A D G 6 string model - B E A D G C B 37″';`

Comment: without new line char ? is it flat string or you have back to new line ?

Comment: Yes,, without new line

Comment: Thank you,, You are 98% closer to actual answer.

Comment: Its also giving `B`

Comment: Please consider switching to the live chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185336/discussion-between-yanis-git-and-imran-hasan).